# How to convert u64 to two u32's as explained below

Tags: c++, c

I have ran into a problem and hoping someone here could help me out.

I have a character array of 15 elements, which is an `Imei` number for a `GSM` module, I am required to convert this character array into two `unsigned long (u32)` numbers such that when their binary representations are concatenated it results in the actual `unsigned long long (u64)` value in the character array, ie the `Imei number`

The reason for this is that the processor we are currently developing on does not support u64's, we would like to transmit this Imei number to a server for decoding.

eg. what I have is

```
unsigned char charArray [15] = {'3','5','3','8','1','6','0','5','4','0','4','5','7','1','3'};
```

and the binary representation of the decimal number `353816054045713` is `1010000011100101100111000001101111001110000010001`

and what I am looking for is a general solution that will give me two unsigned long numbers who's binary representations when concatenated will give me the binary representation of the Imei in decimal.

eg `82379 (10100000111001011)` and `943168529` (`00111000001101111001110000010001`)
when concatenated is `1010000011100101100111000001101111001110000010001` which is `353816054045713`.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a standard-compliant compiler. What is the problem sending a `uint8_t [8]`? Also note: Do not use homebrew fixed-width types. `stdint.h` exists for good reasons.

Comment: You need to solve this using C or C++? 'Cause you know there is quite a difference...

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick **one** of them.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: One way or another, you need `stroll`.  Except that you don't have it, because your system doesn't support 64-bit types.  You can write your own, but it's going to be a little tricky, again because your system doesn't support 64-bit types.  I'm afraid I don't see a solution other than using, or implementing, some multiprecision code, as suggested in user2079303's answer.  You don't necessarily need a full multiprecision library -- all you need is addition, and multiplication by 10, out to 64 bits -- but you're going to need something like that.

Comment: Following up to my previous comment: I assume you know how to write `atoi`.  Rewrite it using `uint32_t[2]` instead of `int`.  Write code to add two  `uint32_t[2]`'s together, handling carry if necessary.  You'll also need to be able to multiply a `uint32_t[2]` by 10.  One way to do that is shift it left by 3 bits (which is the same as multiplying it by 8), and also shift it left by 1 bit (which is the same as multiplying it by 2), then add the two results together.  Naturally you have to take care of a carry when you do the shift left, too.

Comment: The algorithm for adding two `uint32_t[2]`'s together is the same one you learned in elementary school for adding two 2-digit numbers together with carry, except that here you're working in base 4294967296, not base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Unions can do this trick for you:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union {
   uint64_t i64; 
   uint32_t i32[2];
   uint16_t i16[4];   // these lines aren't needed for this code, just here 
   uint8_t i8[8];     // as an example of what else might be useful
} theUnion;

theUnion.i64 = myInt64Value;
printf("First u32 is %u, second u32 is %u\n", theUnion.i32[0], theUnion.i32[1]);
```

Note that you may still have to worry about endian-ness issues if you are transmitting your data to CPUs of different architectures.

Comment: Keep in mind that the question is tagged with C++ along with C. This code invokes undefined behavior in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any 64 bit unsigned type available (really.. !?), you can do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char charArray [15] = {'3','5','3','8','1','6','0','5','4','0','4','5','7','1','3'};
    uint32_t t1 = 0;  // Will hold the lower 32 bits
    uint32_t t2 = 0;  // Will hold the upper 32 bits
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        // Multiply t2 by 10
        t2 = t2 * 10;

        // Loop for multiplying t1 by 10 while checking for overflow
        uint32_t x = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            x = x + t1;
            if (x < t1)
            {
               // Overflow - increment t2
               t2 = t2 + 1;
            }
        }
        t1 = x;

        // Add next digit
        x = t1 + charArray[i]-'0';  // Note the subtraction of '0'
        if (x < t1)
        {
            // Overflow - increment t2
            t2 = t2 + 1;
        }
        t1 = x;
    }

    cout << t1 << " 0x" << hex << t1 << dec << endl;
    cout << t2 << " 0x" << hex << t2 << dec << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
943168529 0x38379c11
82379 0x141cb
```

The solution is probably not performing very well and - most likely - better solutions exists. However, if performance isn't an issue this is a pretty straight forward solutions.

Take care of endianness if you transmit the result to another computer.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses, I have tried this solution and it works every time, I am not really bothered about the performance since this calculation will only ever be executed on initialization. Thank you :) !

Comment: @M.Sheik - glad to hear it helped you. If you found it useful, you welcome to accept and/or upvote the answer. :-) Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be trivially solved by representing the number as a arbitrary-precision integer. Of course, implementing arbitrary-precision arithmetic yourself is non-trivial, but many implementations already exist.

First, construct the AP integer from the string (you'll probably want to null-terminate it for simplicity). Then convert the AP integer into a regular integer of desired bit size to get the lower half. Then shift the AP integer to right for the number of bits equal to the size of the lower integer. Then convert the AP integer again to get the higher half.

So, if you don't want to use an existing AP arithmetic implementation and want to implement it yourself, then you only need to implement construction from string, truncating conversion to regular integer and right shift.

A sidenote: It appears that you assume in your question that (`unsigned`) `long` is 32 bits and (`unsigned`) `long long` is 64bits. Neither of those is guaranteed by the standard. If you need an integer with certain number of bits, you may want to use `<cstdint>` types like `std::int32_t`.

Secondly, don't convert character literals to `unsigned char`. Simply store strings in `char` array.

Thirdly, C and C++ are different languages. I answered from the perspective of C++. C might be different in some details.

Comment: Note: "don't convert char literals to unsigned char" misleads.  `'3','5'..` are character constants of type `int`.  C does not specify a _char literal_.   Assigning them to an `unsigned char` is not a problem.  Saving them as `char` my be a better idea, yet both are acceptable.  Perhaps the result differs in C++.

Comment: @chux I answered from C++ perspective (I've now specified that) and C++ standard does specify character literals [lex.ccon] and their type is `char`, not `int` (unless the character cannot be represented by a single byte). Also, passing a `unsigned char*` to a function that expects `char*` is not allowed in C++ while it is allowed (but recommended, I would assume) in C, which is why storing strings in `unsigned char` arrays makes things unnecessarily complicated.